# Do I need to include Field-Level Security to get on the App Exchange?

Tags: appexchange, field-level-security, crud

I have a list of issues that Salesforce sent me for the security review before my app can be accepted in the AppExchange.

The first section is titled "CRUD and FLS", followed by a lot of examples for CRUD but no mention of FLS.

Checking FLS security throughout the whole application could potentially take hundreds of hours.  Will my app be rejected if I just check for CRUD but not FLS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### FLS

You must make sure that you honor FLS. That does not mean that every trigger, every utility function, etc must check every single field before attempting to access or update the value. It simply means that the front-end UI (any Visualforce) *must* use `apex:inputText` or `apex:outputText` to honor visual field level security, or that any other types of input, such as `apex:input` or `apex:selectList`, *must* honor field level security, if a field is invoked. It is exceptionally unusual to have a FLS violation, since Visualforce automatically honors it at the rendering level with the appropriate use of tags.

The following is okay:

```
<!-- RECOMMENDED -->
<apex:inputField value="{!Object.Field}"/>
```

As is the following:

```
<!-- ACCEPTABLE -->
<apex:input value="{!Object.Field}" rendered="{!$ObjectType.Object.fields.Field.Accessible}" readonly="{!NOT($ObjectType.Object.fields.Field.Editable)}" />
```

But not the following:

```
<!-- BAD -->
<apex:input value="{!Object.Field}" />
```

Or the following:

```
<!-- BAD -->
<apex:input value="{!variableSetFromAField}" />
```

Also, the security scanner will let you know if there are any specific FLS violations (referred to as data tampering), and you'll get a warning to that effect; you can fix these problems manually with very little effort in most cases.

In summary of FLS, you really *have* to go out of your way to violate FLS, and fixing it is easy.

### CRUD

CRUD is significantly more important (and easier to violate), and generally describes situations where a Visualforce page explicitly invokes a "without sharing" class to bypass sharing controls, potentially allowing users to view, modify, or delete records they should not be able to. Triggers are generally immune from this criteria, because triggers must be able to enforce business logic that the user may not have direct access to. Regardless, CRUD is usually equally easy to fix, usually by affixing the "with sharing" keyword on the class.

Please note that CRUD "flags" are not automatic rejections. There are legitimate cases where you need to use inherited or "without sharing" classes, and so long as your explanation is reasonable, you will still pass your review. CRUD is far more likely to show up in the automated scanner report than FLS, because it is far easier to forget to add "with sharing" than it is to purposefully use the wrong tag in a Visualforce page, especially since all the basic tutorials suggest you use `apex:inputField` whenever possible.

### Other Information

For specific questions regarding your review, you should contact the security review team directly. They will help advise you on what needs to be fixed in order to pass your security review, and which items are simply "recommendations" that may not cause you to fail a review.

Simply running a security scan is sufficient. There's no need to "check FLS security throughout the whole application", because the automated scanner will catch any possible violations for you; if it doesn't appear in the report, you do not have a FLS problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  I was confused because I have for example a trigger "with sharing" that does not check for CRUD, and is flagged.  Can I therefore explain this away by saying that it is intended to run in system mode?

Comment: @GeorgeS. Triggers always run in system mode, so you can't have a trigger "with sharing". It's likely you're mis-reading the report. You will probably want to address this specific line entry with someone at the security review team to decypher what the message means, exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the trigger delegates the logic to a "with sharing" class

Comment: @GeorgeS. Odd. I don't see why it would be flagged, because since you're in a with sharing class, CRUD would be automatically enforced (e.g. current user would not be able to query records they don't have read access to). Like I said previously, I'd check with the security review team. As an aside, if the class' code is meant to run in system mode, you need to omit "with sharing" or it won't.

Comment: @sfdcfox Your last comment sounds like you're saying with sharing enforces CRUD access. My understanding is it enforces sharing rules but not CRUD access. The last paragraph on this page outlines my understanding : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm

Answer (score 1):

Although you *should* check for CRUD/FLS, you will not be failed in the security review for not checking CRUD/FLS for custom objects that are not security sensitive. CRUD/FLS must be checked for standard objects (e.g. Account) and security sensitive objects such as financial or health data. The rationale for this is that your app must play well with other apps and with org admin security policies. This means that the big risk is in standard objects accessible to all apps, such as Account. These are also the types of objects that organizations are going to focus on for setting access control policies.

Please be aware that the security scanner no longer performs CRUD/FLS checks -- this query was disabled because it was generating too many false positives. We are hoping to re-enable a better query in the future. Point being that just because the scanner does not return CRUD/FLS issues does not mean that you have addressed this adequately in your code.

Comment: Is there any estimation available for FLS check implementation in security scanner code check?

Comment: @VarunC This is something that we are revisiting. The main problem is that for large apps, we get so many results that it overwhelms the system. We've recently added more capacity and are looking at turning this back on. There are remaining concerns that the result files will get too large to send via email, so we may need to provide truncated results.